# Slave VMs can't ping 8.8.8.8 after router VM reboot

Tags: linux

So im on the cloud and i have a vm (master) that i turned to a router for my others vms (slaves) so they can get access to the internet. For the purpose of this question we will call the master script mr.sh and the script that runs on the slaves sr.sh . After i run both scripts for the first time i can ping 8.8.8.8 from the slave vms fine. But when i reboot the master vm and then rerun the scripts i cant ping 8.8.8.8 from the slave vms. i used the traceroute command to a slave vm and this is the output:

```
 1  master (192.168.0.1)  0.521 ms  0.388 ms  0.364 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
```

i tried to: restart networking on all the machines, flash the ip tables and rerun the scripts, reboot the vms again and retry but with no avail any ideas why is this happening? and how to fix this?

mr.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enabling ipv4 forwarding (cleaning old rules)"
# flushing old rules -- USE WITH CARE
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
# MASQUERADE each request form the inside to the outer world
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# enable IPv4 packet forwarding in the kernel
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "Master is now operating as router"
```

and sr.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash  
ENDPOINT_INTERFACE=$(cat /etc/hosts | grep master | awk '{print $1}')
route add default gw $ENDPOINT_INTERFACE
echo "Gateway now points to $ENDPOINT_INTERFACE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i want to thank both Michael Hampton and Marco for taking the time to answer my question. The problem was something completely different that what i was expecting, Docker was blocking the forwarding of packages on my router-pc. So i followed this article https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router and this article https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-and-docker-firewall-redux-how-to-deal-with-forward-policy-set-to-drop/9953/3 to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your MASQUERADE rule is wrong. It needs to specify the outbound interface, otherwise it will try to NAT all traffic in both directions, causing a total failure in connectivity. You need to specify the outbound interface:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have a problem finding my outbound interface since i'm a beginner to all of that stuff . My provider says that that eth0 is my public network card and eth1 is my private one . After searching on the internet about finding which is the outbound interface i found the command `ip route get an_ip` which returns my public ip and dev eth1 . Is it safe to assume that eth1 is the outbound interface?

Comment: @DeStC3 It probably is today. You may want to try to find out why your interfaces have the names eth0 and eth1 and get that fixed though, before you try to put this in production. This ancient style of naming network interfaces is not a good idea because it cannot be guaranteed they will be the same when you reboot. Look up consistent network device naming for your Linux distribution.

Comment: it seems that i get the exact same problem after i restart the master vm, i checked `ip route get an_ip` and eth1 stills comes up after the reboot but slave can't ping 8.8.8.8 after masters reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the allow FORWARD rules

Instead of running separate `iptable` commands, I suggest you use something like `iptables-restore /etc/firewall.conf`. It flushes the tables that you specify and loads all rules at once.

With contents of `firewall.conf` being:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# Port forward
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.5:80

COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Local server filter rule
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic forwarding
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```